# How can I allow anonymous access to an otherwise protected resource through a unique URL in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

To access resources in my API the user needs to be authorized, which is handled by

```
[Authorize]
```

I need to find a way to generate a unique URL for a specific resource that can be used to access that resource without the user having to authenticate.

Comment: You can have another endpoint (unsecured) that basically accepts a one-off token (stored in DB, etc with expiry information) and uses *that* to log the user in, then redirects to the current endpoint.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that might work, I'll try that! Thank you.

Comment: I suggest using the Data Protection API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-2.1.  You can protect the required information into an encrypted string and put it in the query string of the URL you generate.  You only then have to successfully decrypt the token and validate it's contents to know if it's genuine and you don't have to store anything in the database.

Comment: Use [AllowAnonymous] attribute..

Comment: this may definitely give a starting point. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `Authorize` attribute to the class, which will force all endpoints to require authorization.

Then, by specifying the `AllowAnonymous` attribute on a specific endpoint, you will override the above requirement and allow users to access MyAnonymousEndpoint without being logged in.

```
[Authorize]
public class MySecureClass
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult MyAnonymousEndpoint()
    {

    }
}
```